# path reference is not working in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to import a .js library to my angular project. 
When I set inside `index.html`:

```
<script src="external.js"></script>
```

and inside my component: 
declare var External: any;

I can call `External.myFunc()` and everything works well. 
However, I want to import this library inside my component, and not inside index.html, to do so, I use path reference:

```
/// <reference path="./external.d.ts" />
```

and inside external.d.ts, I import external.js:

```
import './external.js';
```

but I keep getting "External is not defined.."

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing type declarations with their implementations and/or the libraries they represent. Also, never use

```
/// <reference path="..." />
```

you almost never need it. Furthermore, a reference path to a .d.ts file will not cause a JavaScript module it in turn imports to load at runtime, since it is not even available at runtime since it is a `.d.ts`, that is declarations only.

What you want is to do the following

1. remove this immediately

   ```
   <script src="external.js"></script>
   ```
2. remove this immediately

   ```
   /// <reference path="./external.d.ts" />
   ```

   replacing it with this

   ```
   // make sure it is in the right location and adjust path if needed.
   import './external';
   ```
3. You almost certainly need to remove this too!

   ```
   declare var External: any;
   ```

Comment: Did so - I still get "Uncaught ReferenceError:  External is not defined"

Comment: Well, if you were loading it in index.html via a script tag with an unqualified src attribute, you probably need to import it from either an absolute path like `import 'external';` it may not exist where you think it does.

Comment: Also, does it, the JavaScript external.js declare a global variable called `External`? Can't say more at this point...